# How to authenticate amazon s3 endpoint in java

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I've amazon aws s3 endpoint, access key and secret key, i want to validate my endpoint using these key in java, can someone help how to test my endpoint if you can share some sample code will be very helpful.

Thanks

I tried the below code but its not authenticating:

```
public class AmazonS3Example
{
  private static final String SUFFIX = "/";

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(
            "YourAccessKeyID",
            "YourSecretAccessKey");
    AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
    s3client.setEndpoint("http://someendpoing.com");
  }
}
```

Comment: Its not an error, but i guess this is not correct way of authenticating endpoint...

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar issue. I'm setting my local minio S3 endpoint but s3 client still tries to connect some AWS endpoint and fails to connect.

Comment: I am able to authenticate the above way. Are you getting any exception or error?

Answer (score 1):

An endpoint is an Amazon supplied value.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html

E.g. **s3.amazonaws.com** for US Standard.

Or s3-**<region>**.amazonaws.com, E.g. **s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com**

You are using an incorrect endpoint.  Plus in most situations you want to set the Amazon Region, not the endpoint specifically.  See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/create-bucket-get-location-example.html for an example.

With your Account credentials, Region and Bucket name, Amazon S3 API has all it needs to find your files.